# How to add significance bar between subgroups of box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to make a wilcox test and add a significance bar for each group in the boxplot (not between groups). I.e. comparing subgroups ("0", "1") at time 2, 6, and 14.
This is what I have so far:

**WS = time

DV = effect

count = subgroup ("0" or "1")**

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=WS, y=DV, group=count))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(count), group=interaction(WS, count)))
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="smooth", aes(group=factor(count), color =factor(count)))
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2,6,14))
p
```

[Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrsQG.jpg)

When adding

```
p <- p + geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("0", "1")),
              map_signif_level=TRUE,test='wilcox.test')
```

to the above, I get the following error:

```
Error in f(...) : 
  Can only handle data with groups that are plotted on the x-axis
```

I assume that a comparison can only be made on if the data is on the x-axis. However, I want to keep the plot pretty much as it is right now, with time 2, 6 and 14 on the x-axis. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? You could post the output of `dput(data)`or `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Simon, here is the dput() of my data.   
structure(list(WS = c(2L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 
2L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 6L, 14L
), DV = c(19.87, 17.58, 3.87, 28, 29.68, 22.57, 26.73, 8.75, 
13.19, 0.53, 39.63, 41.96, 18.14, 35.01, 35.5, 11.31, 10.94, 
5.42, 0.85, 8.55, 3.86, 0.86, 18.97, 14.04, 1.99), count = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the vignette of `ggsignif` (see `??ggsignif`) I understand that for layers that use `position='dodge'` (which is the case for your boxplots as you have the grouping with an intercation) you'll need to provide the position and the annotation (label) yourself.

You can calculate all the values like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=WS, y=DV, group=count))
p <- p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(count), group=interaction(WS, count)))
p <- p + stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="smooth", aes(group=factor(count), color =factor(count)))
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2,6,14))

p.values <- sapply(split(data, data$WS), function(x){wilcox.test(DV~count, x)$p.value})
labels <- symnum(p.values, corr = FALSE, cutpoints = c(0,  .001,.01,.05, 1), symbols = c("***","**","*","n.s."))
y.values <- sapply(split(data, data$WS), function(x){max(sapply(split(x, x$count), function(xx){boxplot(x$DV, plot=F)$stats[5, ]}))})+2

p <- p + geom_signif(y_position = y.values, xmin = unique(data$WS)-.4, xmax = unique(data$WS)+.4, annotations = labels)
p
```

This gives:
[image]

Comment: How to do if you x axis is categorical?

Comment: And is a legend possible when doing manually

Comment: @BrianWiley: You can perform maths for x positions fpr factors (categorial variables) by converting them into their numerical representation: `p <- p + geom_signif(y_position = y.values, xmin = unique(as.numeric(data$WS))-.4, xmax = unique(as.numeric(data$WS))+.4, annotations = labels)` (this would work after transforming `data$WS <- as.factor(data$WS)`)

Comment: Thanks I found that out. Now I am trying now to hide brackets if not significant and add legend.  Maybe need different package

Comment: Since your supplying values manually you can just remove those that are not significant. `n.s <- which(p.values>=.05)
if (length(n.s)<length(p.values)) {
  p.values <- p.values[-n.s]
  labels <- labels[-n.s]
  y.values <- y.values[-n.s]
  x.values <- x.values[-n.s]
  p <- p + geom_signif(y_position = y.values, xmin = x.values-.19, xmax = x.values+.19, annotations = labels)
}`